Trying to access MangoDB particular directory on Postman
Can someone tell me how can I ask data from MangoDB particular directory let's say 'testing' rather then whole database which have all original data. I want data on postman from test directory.
I have tried for connection is following:
router.get('/get_company_ids', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const companies = await Company.find({}, { _id: 1 });      `here I found the company`
        const companyIds = companies.map(company => company._id);  `here mapping all company id's`
        res.json({ company_ids: companyIds });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
});


Do you mean MongoDB? MangoDB is a parody database.
